# catch 22 with git permissions for private repos

Tags: git, ubuntu, permissions, controls, version

I'm getting the following when I try to send a dir from my server to a private repos with github..

```
$:/home/my_site/$ git push origin master

   Enter passphrase for key '/home/adamgamb/.ssh/id_rsa': 
   error: unable to create directory for .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
   error: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'.
   Everything up-to-date
```

Currently, if I try to use git with out sudo I get this error because the files can't be accessed, however, if I use sudo the git `publickey` is rejected (it is in the ~/.ssh of the user im executing this as)

Can anyone explain how to avoid this problem?

```
$: sudo git push origin master
  Permission denied (publickey).
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Please do not use *sudo* as the first response to a permission problem. If you expect to be able to run a command as a normal user, then find and fix the permission problem itself. At the very best, running as root will temporarily cover up the problem; usually it creates even more permission problems (files created while running as root will not (usually) be writable by your normal user).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The directory that it's complaining about not being able to create is actually in your home directory -- i.e., ~/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master . Probably what happened is that you ran git under sudo, created these files as root, and now you can't access them. As root, you could chown -R adamgamb  ~adamgamb/.git, then try again as you.

Comment: Struggled for 24 hrs and then saw the answer from demi god